# Retrieve GET request from Block Plugin

Tags: blocks, 8, plugins

I'd like a block plugin to display content dependent on a GET request.
Inside my block plugin I have

```
class BlogPage extends BlockBase {
    public function build() {
        $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
            ->condition('type', 'blog_post')
            ->sort('created', 'DESC')
            ->range(0, $range);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

I'd like to make $range retrieve info from a GET request. For example I'd like
127.0.0.1/page?range=5 to make $range = 5.
I've tried

```
$range = Request::get('range');
```

But that does not work. Is there a way to return the values in a GET request from inside the block plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [get the current request object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.2.x) first:

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
$range = $request->get('range');
```

Or

```
$range = \Drupal::request()->get('range');
```

Comment: and it'll need a cache flush ;)

    drush cr

or manually via admin/config/development/performance

Comment: If you setup your cache tags right it shouldn't need to rebuild caches.  A rebuild isn't going to be all that useful anyway since build() will not be called most of the time if the cache is still considered valid.

Comment: Whenever I attempt this I get Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block\Drupal' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/aaep/web/modules/custom/mymodule/src/Plugin/Block/MyPlugin.php on line 46

Comment: Turns out I needed a \ before the Drupal::request();

Comment: I added that to the example since that's true in most contexts.